# Touchless Vision C# webcam wrapper, can't run without VS installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, wrapper, webcam

So I've been hunting around for a good way to utilize a webcam from within a C# application. I tried a p/invoke dll which turned out to be inexplicably and irreproduceably buggy. After tinkering with a few others that either weren't suitable or were utterly archaic, I was referred to this:

http://jakemdrew.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/controlling-your-web-camera-using-c/#comment-15

It's the Touchless Vision code with a C# wrapper updated to work in VS 2010. It works wonderfully...as long as VS is installed on the machine. Download and run that release build on anything that doesn't and it will throw an error claiming that it can't find WebCamLib.dll or one of its dependencies. The fun part is that I've already integrated this into the project. It works great, but I'd like to be able to distribute this without additional installers or requiring VS 2010 to be installed on everything. What gives here?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Aforge.net libraries([Aforge.net](http://www.aforgenet.com/)) without any problems on multiple computers even without VS installed.

But are you sure WebCamLib.dll is copied in the app directory? Aforge.Net also needs some dlls copied to computers, but if you have set Copy Local property to true, it should be inside the Debug/Release directory, also it will be in the directory when you release your app using Publish.

Sample:

1. Add Aforge.Controls.dll to your toolbox items
2. In designer put VideoSourcePlayer control in your form
3. Add `private FilterInfoCollection videoDevices;` in form class
4. Add into form initializer (or in function that you want to start your camera)

```
videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

    foreach (FilterInfo fi in videoDevices)
    {
      this.videoSourcePlayer1.VideoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(MonikerString);
      this.videoSourcePlayer1.Start();
      break;
    }
```

Now you should be getting image from webcam in VideoSourcePlayer control. You can use NewFrame event of VideoSourcePlayer control to get access to each frame camera is sending and to save or change image.

Comment: Yes. Everything is in the application directory, WebCamLib.dll included. The release build of the demo itself won't run on a computer without VS, and naturally the same applies to anything that tries to integrate it. I took a look at Aforge a while ago, but the thing is enormous and I couldn't dig out how to simply grab an image from a webcam in all of it.

Comment: It is actually pretty simple to grab images in Aforge using new frame event. I will add some somple code to my answer. Aforge is a little big, but only showing image from webcam is matter of few lines of code

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a whirl if I can't get this one figured out in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

well some time has passed since the question but, just for the sake of solving it I´ll say this:

Supposing that you have the references to the dlls and the files where they should be the only thing left to do is check the dll dependencies, in this case
the programmer of the touchless and webcamlib dlls didn´t care much for "versioning" so, find the c++ vs2012 redistribution for x64 and x86 and install them, then run your App and carry on with your Project.